# Not able to generate signed - Invalid keystore format

Tags: android, apk, release, signed, gradlew

I recently started a new android project. I moved my keystore file into this project but when I try to generate the signed .APK with the commando: `./gradlew assembleRelease` I get this error:

[image]

Do anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: No... Unfortunately not